# Mesh won't bevel

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edit-mode, bevel

I have two identical objects (at least I cannot find a difference), but one can be beveled, the other not. Any idea why? I already looked for double vertices.

[image: Screenshot]

The blender file (version 2.8) can be downloaded here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uovs29ujbbzw6tr/TestKey.blend?dl=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have an hidden internal face.

Doing *Search* (<kbd>F3</kbd>) > "*Select Non Manifold*" reveals the problem:

[image]

In this case, all you need to do is to remove the face: <kbd>X</kbd> > "*Faces*".

[image]

**Note**: if you use the Bevel modifier with "*Clamp Overlap*", it probably works, without the need to fix the topology. But this is a bad practice as you can then easily forget that your topology needs to be fixed, and the problem can resurface later (boolean, sculpting, 3D printing, UV unwrapping)

Comment: Thanks Nicola! This is something I would have searched forever, as I had not yet heard about this function.

Comment: looks like this function is not available in blender 2.91, this search does not come up in edit mode.